# Qt5.0 How to create per-user persistent data directory

Tags: qt5

I want to store per-user persistent data, here's the code

```
QDir::toNativeSeparators(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(
                         QStandardPaths::DataLocation) + "/random.xxx");
```

It displays the location correctly but, the directories is not automatically created
i.e.

> .local/share/organization name/application name/random.xxx

application name and organization name are already specified:

```
QApplication::setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
QApplication::setOrganizationName(ORGANIZATION_NAME);
```

When I manually create the directories, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works to me:

```
QApplication::setApplicationName("MyApp");
QApplication::setOrganizationName("Me");

#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    this->HomePath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);
#else
    this->HomePath = QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `QDir::toNativeSeparators` call in `QDir::mkpath`.